# Create column in SQL that indicates if at least one row meets a condition for a given ID

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows:

| ID | YearlyAwardStatus | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Awarded | 2014 |
| 101 | Not Awarded | 2015 |
| 102 | Not Awarded | 2014 |
| 102 | Not Awarded | 2015 |

I want to create a column via a SQL query that will show if a given ID has ever been 'Awarded' across multiple years.

| ID | YearlyAwardStatus | Year | EverAwarded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Awarded | 2014 | Yes |
| 101 | Not Awarded | 2015 | Yes |
| 102 | Not Awarded | 2014 | No |
| 102 | Not Awarded | 2015 | No |

---

I have tried using CASE but have not been able to get it to return a result that analyzes more than one row at a time.

Comment: Look up and try window functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquerys tochekc if a ID has a award recieved

```
SELECT
ID,     YearlyAwardStatus,  Year
, CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT1 FROM table1 t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID and t2.YearlyAwardStatus = 'Awarded') THEM 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END   EverAwarded
FROM table1 t1
```